# how to create engine from flask-SQLAlchemy object?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, \
 render_template, flash
import pypyodbc
import pdb
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mssql+pypyodbc://SERVERNAME/DB'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.route('/')
def main():

    result = db.engine.execute('SELECT * from Table')

    return render_template('index.html')
```

This results in the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I cannot find an example of this in the documentation...what is the correct way to use the SQLAlchemy object's engine?

Thanks!

Comment: You've some issues with your Python installation.

Comment: @IljaEverila - any elaboration you can provide on that?

Comment: I'm sorry, but no. If you search using the exception, as I did, you'll find a variety of issues that have in common that the python installation is flawed, such as using binary incompatible versions of packages, but no single solution.